# Use other aggregate operators before search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've been exploring Atlas search and using its index to do a search on the data but before using the "$search" operator in the pipeline I want to narrow down the data by using a filter before that. But MongoDB doesn't allow that. Is there any way in which I can use a $match or any other operator before using $search to narrow down the data and improve performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is no, as specified in the [docs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/query-syntax/#behavior):

> $search must be the first stage of any pipeline it appears in

The reason for this as `$search` has to use the "special" text index `atlas search` builds, once you've loaded results into memory it cannot be used anymore.

Unfortunately there is no work around or "hack" you can use, I recommend considering why you need such usage, as it sounds a bit of an anti pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I found a small workaround for my use case. In search rather than using text operator, I'm using the compound operator and using filter and text in that.

Comment: @akshit could you provide an example